# java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Unknown host specified

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have a server name, port number, database name, domain, username, and password.
I entered the connection string using the below format:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//serverName:portNumber//domain
```

But got the below error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Unknown host specified

How do I specify the connection string ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your connection string it is difficult to tell what might be the actual problem, but the error is basically letting you know it cannot reach whatever machine you specified. Here is a good link regarding Oracle connection strings using Java:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html

Comment: i cannot put the actuals as it is sensitive information.But i will put something instead of that. i got information like : Server : "abcd.efg.org" port : 1234, database name : "abcdefgh" domain "dfghjklop". My connection url which i gave was : jdbc:oracle:thin@//abcd.efg.org:1234/dfghjklop  . My confusion is , SID or server name is the domain name what i have ?

Comment: You do not actually need the @ symbol in there or the //. It would need to be something like this:

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
  ("jdbc:oracle:thin:nameofcomputerhere:1521:orcl", "usernamehere", "passwordhere");

Comment: No no i am not using jdbc.i am trying connect in squirrelSQL to oracle thin driver.

Answer (score 0):

jdbc:oracle:thin:@DBhost:DBport:DBname

Answer (score -4):

Path is wrong
Just run this:
jdbc:oracle:thin://@serverName:portNumber/databaseName